# Woocommerce showing "NULL" when completing orders manually

Tags: php, wordpress, null, woocommerce

I've recently found that since I've installed this plugin (http://codecanyon.net/item/license-manager-for-woocommerce/5089794) whenever I try to manually change the status of an order (switching from processing to completed or the other way back) it loads a blank page when it just shows: NULL.

The strange thing is that if I back to the Order page and reload it, the status changes.
Another hint may be for example that the url when I arrive at the blank page with the "NULL" written in it, is something like this:

```
wp-admin/edit.php?s=&post_status=all&post_type=shop_order&_wpnonce=2d037c85cf&_wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit.php%3Fpost_type%3Dshop_order&action=mark_processing&m=0&_customer_user=&paged=1&mode=list&post%5B%5D=1117&action2=-1
```

What I can see there (and I might be wrong), is that after the _wpnonce appears a redirect with wrong values :S

Anything could help me? I'm kinda lost and I can't figure out where does this error comes from or make it right.

If I disable the plugin, everythings goes alright.

Greetings!

Comment: If you purchased this plugin you should report the problem to the developer.

Comment: He's not making any update as he promised :S